# Request failed: internal server error (500) and Cocoa error 3840, Invalid value around character 0 responses AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

It appears to be working in web:

Web Response Headers:

```
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:394
    Content-Type:application/json
    Date:Sun, 22 Mar 2015 18:36:06 GMT
    Server:nginx/1.6.2
    Vary:Accept-Encoding
    X-Powered-By:Express
```

Web Request Headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NDVjYzNjYzQ2N2I3YjAyMDBhMWNkOWEiLCJpYXQiOjE0MjcwNDM3Mzk1NjQsImV4cCI6MTQ5MDExNTczOTU2NH0.Xqm-b12QWcEa6MPXyKa1E8m88hGZI9KfJl7Img3mACU
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:225
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Web Request Payload:

```
{"id":"550f15122cc2708c2d9c65b8","users":["xiruken@gmail.com"],"welcomeMessage":"Hi there. We’ll be using Next24 to keep track of our daily high priority items as a group during this project.","newUser":"xiruken@gmail.com"}
```

But not working in my native iOS project using objective-C...

Same parameters:

`NSDictionary` query:

```
{
    id = 550f15122cc2708c2d9c65b8;
    newUser = "xiruken@gmail.com";
    users =     (
        "xiruken@gmail.com"
    );
    welcomeMessage = "Hi there. We will be using Next24 to keep track of our daily high priority items as a group during this project.";
}
```

`AFNetworking` code:

```
-(AFHTTPSessionManager *)sessionManager2{
    if(!_sessionManager2){
        _sessionManager2 = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL: [NSURL URLWithString:API_URL]];
        AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
        [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
        [_sessionManager2 setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];
        _sessionManager2.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
        NSArray *acceptedTypes = @[@"text/html", @"application/json", @"text/plain"];
        _sessionManager2.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithArray:acceptedTypes];
        //add token
        if([Helpers isLoggedIn]){
            UserDM *user = [UserDM loadCustomObjectWithKey:DEFAULT_CURRENT_USER];
            [self.sessionManager2.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", user.accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        }
    }
    return _sessionManager2;
}
```

Using `AFJSONResponseSerializer` is giving me this error:

```
2015-03-23 03:28:26.773 Next25[5801:302572] Failed! Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7fdbb252a6e0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdbb252c410 "Request failed: internal server error (500)"}
```

I even `allowFragments` and even set `acceptableContentTypes`

And changing it to `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` is giving me a different error:

```
2015-03-23 03:30:30.797 Next25[5852:303849] Failed! Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0x7fb129e4e930 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fb129e36320> { URL: https://myproject.com/api/projects/550f15122cc2708c2d9c65b8/invite_users } { status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 21;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sun, 22 Mar 2015 19:26:56 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = Express;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myproject.com/api/projects/550f15122cc2708c2d9c65b8/invite_users, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<496e7465 726e616c 20536572 76657220 4572726f 72>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Charles to verify the request? It looks more like a request issue causing a server issue and bad response

Comment: Hi please close this thread. I had finally found the answer.

I forgot adding this `self.sessionManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];`

Comment: You need to delete the question ;-)